# Third-party security providers like Google, Twitter etc. in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have created a standard ASP.Net web project in Visual Studio 2013 and enabled authentication.

A class called 'StartupAuth.cs' is created auotmatically, with following lines. When the app runs on localhost dev server it throws an exception as pasted in screen shot below the code. I need to have it run in localhost dev server when authenticating through Google, Twitter, Facebook and Window Live.

**Question**: Can I provide any valid string values to the parameters - clientId, clientSecret and appId? If not, then from where do I get valid values for these?

```
        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
            clientId: "",
            clientSecret: "");

        app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
           consumerKey: "",
           consumerSecret: "");

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
           appId: "",
           appSecret: "");

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "",
            ClientSecret = ""
        });
```

**Authentication Exception Thrown**
[image: Authentication Error]

**UPDATE 1**:

Since OAuth2 is the latest for third-party authentication, the instructions at following URL should be used: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on. I followed the steps at above URL, and found that Google authentication on localhost worked perfectly.

**NOTE**: The instructions at this url (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services) are for OpenID authentication which is different from the latest OAuth2 authentication, and therefore will not work for Google authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot enter any string. You will need to register with each provider to get the parameters that you need.

See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services for instructions on how to do this.

Comment: It seems that this url might provide more latest information on external authentication since OAuth2 is the current trend: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on